# Realm creating same object every time API hit server

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using realm in Swift and I'm having issues updating objects.

I am using swift and using realm to store data. but its storing data every time Api hit sever and creating same object (duplicate object) every time and to solve this i used update function and getting another error i don't understand what is the problem.

plz help me to solve this problem.

[this is the error m getting after adding primary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqhgL.png)

Comment: What about some code ? :)

Comment: The error message is rather complete. You should start by following these suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions here as Eric suggested:

**1. If you don't have any data you want to hold on to:**

You can delete the app from the iPhone and launch again since you changed the data model of Realm. This will give you a clean Realm file and then you can test your app.

**2. You want to preserve the data you already have in the Realm file:**

Perform a migration as described [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) in the Realm documentation.

I guess first option is more suitable in this case since you said that you have duplicate data that you don't want in your database and deleting the app and installing again will save you the effort of deleting the duplicate data.

Comment: Thank you! i dint publish the app i am building the app, and every time its creating  duplicate object, 2nd one is perfect.

Comment: i m using 2 VC and 2 VC have the function to hit server n get response from server ... but every  time i m reopen 2nd Vc its creating same object multiple time ...like for first time its 4 object and 2nd time is become 8 and 3 time 12...... its not removing or replacing previous data.